# Creating an adjacency lists

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, adjacency-list

I'm learning to create adjacency lists and am very new to this. I'm trying to test one on my program. I wanted to create one vertex in the linked lists and then create a list or "edge" within that linked list. I create one linked here but not sure how to actually create one inside the linked list. I've created and tested my linked list class and I know it works, I just need to create a way to implement that into adjacency lists now. Also, I CAN'T use any list functions from the C++ library.

Am I heading in the right direction at all with my code?

```
#include "Vertex.h"

Vertex::Vertex(){
    neighbors = new LinkedList();
    discover = 0;
    finish = 0;
    pi = NULL;
    color = "white";
}

Vertex::~Vertex(){
   delete neighbors;
}

void Vertex::insert(Vertex* vertex){

    LinkedList *temp = new LinkedList();

if(index == 0){
    temp->insertElement(vertex);
    index++;
    if(index != 0){
        neighbors->insertElement(vertex);
    }
}
```

}
Here's my main. Thanks in advance!

```
 #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> //to use cin and cout
#include <string> //to use strings
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

int main (){

Vertex *vertex1 = new Vertex();

for (int i =0; i < 10; i++){
   vertex1->insert(vertex1);
}
```

**Edit fixed a few things**

Comment: There are too many `new`s in your code. Where is your copy constructor etc?

Comment: would I create a while loop or something with an index and increment the objects created instead? @NeilKirk

Comment: I don't understand. You also shouldn't be using static variables in your function.

Comment: @NeilKirk I changed my main slightly.

Comment: Why does `vertex1` have to be allocated with new? What happens to `temp`? You allocate it and then leak it. Modern C++ is about using as few news as possible in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: To create an adjacency list you can use the STL containers like this:

`std::map<Vertex *, std::list<Vertex*>> adjacency_list;`

Comment: @NeilKirk Does my updated code make a little more sense? I want to create a linked list within the linked list. That's how you would do an adjacency list correct?

Comment: @DarienPardinas unfortunately I need to build my own data structure here

Comment: You would create `class Vertex { std::list<T> neighbors; };` note there is no pointer, no need for new, nothing in destructor. Any well-designed data structure you create should follow a similar principle.

Comment: If you say "I need to build my own data structure" then your question is not about adjacency matrixes, but about implementing basic data structures such as linked lists. Before you can think of implementing an adjacency matrix, you first need to come up with a solid, debugged linked list implementation. Once you have that done, and only then, can you think about using it to implement more complicated data structures, such as adjacency matrixes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see. I know that my linked list works correct and is solid, just need to figure out how to implement it, and then implement with the adjacency list.

Comment: @NeilKirk Ah okay. I'll work on that.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. If you say "I know that my linked list works correct and is solid", then you don't need to "figure out how to implement it". You must've already implemented it, if you are going on the record that it's "correct and solid".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What I mean is I need to figure out how to implement it into the adjacency list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct approach would be that each vertex's LinkedList would contain a list of all other vertices this vertex is adjacent to.

You didn't provide the details of your LinkedList implementation, and I presume that your `insert()` method's purpose is to record that two vertices are adjacent to each other, that `this` is adjacent to the `vertex` parameter.

If these assumptions are correct, then I would expect that your `insert()` method should look something like this:

```
void Vertex::insert(Vertex* vertex)
{
    neighbors->add(vertex);
    vertex->neighbors->add(this);
}
```

You have a `neighbors` member in the `Vertex` class that I am presuming would contain a list of pointers to other `Vertex`es that are adjance to this one.

Therefore, to record that two vertices are adjacent to each other, you have to record each one of them in the other vertex's `neighbors` method.

You will simply need to implement `add()`, to append a pointer to your linked list.

Now, when you need to find all vertices adjacent to the given `Vertex`, you'll just iterate over the vertices in its `neighbors` link list. So, iterating over each vertex in the pair would, eventually, include the other vertex too.

Your homework assignment is:

1) Your destructor is incomplete. Simply deleting the `neighbors` member would only work if you'll always delete all vertices in the matrix. If you wish to have the ability to remove vertices from an adjacency matrix, but to still keep the rest of it, you will obviously need to remove the `Vertex` being destroyed from the `neighbors` list in all the `Vertex`s that the vertex being destroyed is adjacent to.

2) Some basic error checking, to do something sensible if your code attempts to link two adjacent vertices after they've already been linked as adjacent to each other.